# Swing: move JPanel

Tags: java, swing, location, jpanel

I have 2 jpanels, one is used as a header for another. I want to hide panel with content and move header down when clicked on header (like minimizing). I am able to hide panel, but can't change the location of another one. Here is the code:

```
 private void dbStatsLabelMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)     {                                          
    if (report1Panel.isVisible()) {
        report1Panel.setVisible(false);
        Point p = reportHeaderPanel.getLocation();
        p.y = p.y + 100;
        reportHeaderPanel.setLocation(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: What layout manager are you using?

Comment: I'm using free layout (in Netbeans)

Comment: 1) By 'free layout' DYM a [tag:null-layout-manager] or 'Free Design' which uses a `GroupLayout`?  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3)  Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever) to inform a person of a new comment.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I meant "Free Design"

Comment: The problem is the layout manager is making the decisions on where your components should be positioned, so event though you set the location, your layout manager has overridden this choice with what it things is correct

Comment: @MadProgrammer so what manager should I use for that purpose?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried to use null Layout and it worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove (then add if necessary) `report1Panel` instead of hiding it (then revalidate parent component) - the behaviour will depend on the layout now. If you provide "auto resizing", your "header" component should expand to the parent size.

Other solution would be setting size of `report1Panel` - horizontal or vertical - to zero. Here again - you should provide "auto resizing" functionality

And as @StanislavL mentioned you can use `JSplitPane` with event on header click:

```
splitPane.setDividerLocation(0); //or
splitPane.setDividerLocation(1.0);
```